# Alexa skill builder beta : builds forever

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Under alexa skill kit, when I tried the Skill builder beta and configured the intents and utterances and finally clicked build mode, it builds forever and never stops. It keeps spinning and I am not able to opt out of beta version too. Anyone facing the same problem? Is there a work around.

Comment: Builds for me. Give it time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to delete your current skill from the skill kit and re-add. The first time you enter the interaction model step, you can put in your own JSON and not go through the beta builder.